# Getting a segmentation fault in C with usage of strings, pointers, and functions

Tags: c

**EDIT: solved it, turns out I should use** `%c` **not** `%s` **because foodSelect and foodSize are characters not strings :P thanks**

I'm trying to pass 3 values to the function `output`: foodChoice, foodSelect, foodSize (and foodOrderNum, and foodSubtotal but I haven't gotten around to that yet).

However, when I try to printf `foodSelec`t, I get a segmentation fault, but when I try to print `foodChoice`, I don't. When I try to printf `foodSize` it just shows nothing.

source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void question (char choice[]);
int output(char *foodChoice, char *foodSelect, char *foodSize);


void question (char choice[]) {

    char choiceYesNo;
    char *foodOptions;
    char *foodChoice;
    char *foodSelect;
    char *foodSize;
    int foodOrderNum = 0;
    float foodSubtotal = 0;

    switch (choice[0]) {
        case 'f':
            foodChoice = "Fish";
            foodOptions = "(K- Haddock, T- Halibut)";
            break;
        case 'c':
            foodChoice = "Chips";
            foodOptions = "(C- Cut, R- Ring)";
            break;
        case 'd':
            foodChoice = "Drinks";
            foodOptions = "(S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea)";
            break;
    }

    printf("Do you order %s? (Y/N): ", foodChoice);
        scanf("%c", &choiceYesNo);
    printf("%s choice %s: ", foodChoice, foodOptions);
        scanf("%s", &foodSelect);
    printf("What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): ");
        scanf("%s", &foodSize);
    printf("How many orders do you want? (>=0): ");
        scanf("%d", &foodOrderNum);
    output(foodChoice, foodSelect, foodSize);
}

int output(char *foodChoice, char *foodSelect, char *foodSize) {

    // printf("You ordered %s: %s - SIZE: %s   amount ordered: , subtotal price: \n", 
    // foodChoice, foodSelect, foodSize);

    printf("\n\n%s\n", foodSelect);
    // printf("\n\n%s\n", foodSelect);

}

int main() {

    question("chips");


}
```

Comment: You don't need to edit your question to say it's solved! Just click on the checkbox near the answer that solved your question to select it as the official answer to the question. This is much more visible than editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for:

char *foodOptions;
char *foodChoice;
char *foodSelect;
char *foodSize;

Do [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and allocate memory. Note that:

```
char *foodChoice="Fish";
```

And

```
char *foodChoice;
foodChoice="Fish";
```

are not the same.

Comment: Not allowed to use malloc for we have not used it in class. Not sure why you used `foodChoice` as an example since that's the only one I have working right now haha.

Comment: Either malloc or just an array `char foodChoice[MAX_EXPECTED_LENGTH]`

Comment: I just used one of your variables to point out your error, that's it. The same applies to other pointer variables you used as well. If don't want to use malloc then declare them as @stanwise said.

Comment: On a second thought, there is no error here. You use these pointers just to reference static strings defined in the code, which is correct. The way you wrote it is not very readable though.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you pass `&foodSelect` to `scanf`, which is incorrect for C strings. You should pass `foodSelect` instead, no ampersand.

You should also allocate sufficient space to store the values the users enter, and instruct `scanf` on the max size of the buffer.

```
#define MAX_BUF 128

...
char foodSelect[MAX_BUF];
...
scanf("%127s", foodSelect);
```

Comment: If the buffer size if `128`, you should use `%127s` because of the null terminator. Otherwise you are vulnerable to an off-by-one overflow.